# create a simple tilemap programatically

Tags: iphone, tiles, cocos2d-iphone, roguelikes

i am working on a tile roguelike
i got some of the basics working using this tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d

but i want to be able to create a map programatically instead of using the tiled editor

just add a NSArray of sprites/tiles to my CCLayer derived class or something, or should i make use of the CCTMXTiledMap class?

can anyone gimme some hints about how to do this? or know of a tutorial or sample code somewhere?

thanks a lot

Comment: I suggest looking into the CCTMXTileMap and CCTMXLayer class and see how they operate. Perhaps that will help you figure out if this is feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need a CCTMXLayer, there is no need for any thing else. but you'll need to initialize it properly. for that reason I suggest you use some TMX file generated with Tiled editor and then load it into your program. there is a GID value for each tile in TMXLayer and you can easily edit it. by changing that value the tile for that position will change. if you set a tile's GID to 0 TMXLayer will automatically delete tile at that position otherwise, it'll change(or create) the ccSprite instance at that position.

Comment: This is a clever solution. It didn't occur to me just to load a "blank" map and then modify it to make it random.